# Access search form - search a delimited string

Tags: ms-access, search

I have created a simple search form with the ability to search for an individual Box reference number.  The output is a report with the box number (or list of box numbers when the search returns multiple matches).  For example searching for ABC111, returns a report like:

```
Box      Description
ABC1110  Stuff
ABC1114  More stuff
ABC1119  Even more stuff
```

I use the following Criteria in my Search_Query

```
Like "*" & [forms]![Search_form]![Boxref] & "*"
```

But my customer wants to paste a list of boxes in the BOX Ref field like:
ABC1110, ADF1234, AGT2112

...and have the report display like this:

```
Box      Description
ABC1110  Stuff
ADF1234  Cool stuff
AGT2112  More cool stuff
```

What criteria command do I need to write to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it this way

```
IN ("*ABC1110*","*ADF1234*","*AGT2112*")
```

or if you want you can use the textboxes of the search form

```
Criteria ="In ("
with [forms]![Search_form]
    Criteria = Criteria & "*" & ![Boxref1] & "*"
    Criteria = Criteria & ",*" & ![Boxref2] & "*"
    Criteria = Criteria & ",*" & ![Boxref3] & "*"
    ......
end with
Criteria = Criteria & ")"
```

Or even write a loop to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions in your search criteria , go through below links you will get some idea

http://timothychenallen.blogspot.in/2006/05/ms-access-vba-regular-expressions-regex.html

http://bricestacey.com/2010/07/09/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-Access.html